# SQL: Consolidating similar values of a column in a table and assign them an identifier

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have a table as follows:

```
IndentNo     MaterialId
-----------------------
1001         22345
1001         23457
1001         24456
1002         22345
1002         23457
1002         24456
1003         29987
1003         22345
1003         24456
```

Now I want club those Indents based on following conditions:

```
1. Same MaterialId
2. Same count of MaterialId
```

Therefore `IndentNo` 1001 and 1002 should be consolidated and the resultant table should look like below:

```
 Consolidation_No    IndentNo     MaterialId
 --------------------------------------------
   CON_1              1001         22345
   CON_1              1001         23457
   CON_1              1001         24456
   CON_1              1002         22345
   CON_1              1002         23457
   CON_1              1002         24456
```

I am using the following query:

```
 SELECT 
     a."IndentNo", a."Mat_List", a."Mat_Count" 
 FROM 
     (SELECT 
          "IndentNo", 
          STRING_AGG(CAST("MaterialId" AS varchar),',') AS "Mat_List", 
          COUNT(DISTINCT("MaterialId")) AS "Mat_Count" 
      FROM 
          table 
      GROUP BY 
          "IndentNo") a
 INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT 
          "IndentNo", 
          STRING_AGG(CAST("MaterialId" AS varchar),',') AS "Mat_List",
          COUNT(DISTINCT("MaterialId")) AS "Mat_Count" 
      FROM 
          table
      GROUP BY 
          "IndentNo") x ON a."Mat_List" = x."Mat_List"
                        AND a."Mat_Count" = x."Mat_Count"
```

The above query is producing result not as per my requirement.How can I have the `Consolidation_No` column. Besides, is the 2nd criteria being fulfilled by above query?

Comment: So, you want to generate a new `Consolidation_No` for the set of `MaterialId` values that `IdentNo`=1003 contains? Smells like relational-division ...

Comment: Yes. Precisely.

Comment: What is a `club`?  Is it somehow related to the data you are showing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method is to aggregate into a string or array and compare them.  Then generate the final table:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by materials) as consolidation_num
from (select im.*,
             count(*) over (partition by materials) as num_indentno
      from (select indentno,
                   string_agg(materialid::text, '' order by materialid::text) as materials
            from precontract.tblindentdetails t
            group by indentno
           ) im
     ) im join
     precontract.tblindentdetails t
     on t.indentno = im.indentno
where im.num_indentno > 1;
```

The consolidation number is a number here.  You can convert it to some other format if you like.

Comment: The above solution is not working. `ERROR:  relation "t" does not exist`

Comment: @pythondumb . . . That is an alias for your table.  Put in your table name and give it the alias `t`.

Comment: I am aware that `t` is the alias. Can you please modify the answer, given the actual table name is `precontract.tblindentdetails`? Because I have tried but it is still giving the same error.